# Can I pass parameters of a function as part of a query in bigquery?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
async function test(p1) {
  let [result] = await bigquery.query({
    query: [
      'SELECT url',
      'FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested`',
      'WHERE repository.owner = @owner'

    ].join(' '),
    params: {
      owner: p1
    }
  });
  result.forEach(row => {
    console.log(url)
  }
}
```

> error : (node:19492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Undeclared query parameters

To write a big query, pass the function's parameters as part of the query
I used the query statement provided by bigquery. In the node.js environment.
However, I can not save the @owner that stores p1.

The following documents are related to this.
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/2.0.x/BigQuery

To send a function's parameters as part of a query in bigquery
What should I do? The node.js environment.

Comment: Do you get a different error if you put a string literal in place of `p1`? I'm wondering if `p1` is not defined. The code that you have looks correct based on [the example in the tests](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/system-test/bigquery.ts#L1055).

Comment: What is the value of `p1` when you invoke your test function?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard p1 is string , ex) 'PWG'

Comment: @vinoaj p1 is string, ex)'PWG'

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that you did `console.log(url)` instead of `console.log(row.url)`

This is the full code I used to verify this

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}

import BigQuery from '@google-cloud/bigquery'

describe('Check BigQuery', async () => {

    it('Test param', async () => {
        let result = await test('panada')

    })

    async function test(p1) {
        try {
            const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: `myProject`,
                keyFilename: '/Users/tamirklein/ssh/9473b308ab0e.json'
            })

            let query = [
                'SELECT url',
                'FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested`',
                'WHERE repository.owner = @owner'

            ].join(' ')

            console.log(`query is: ${query}`)
            let [result] = await bigquery.query({
                query,
                params: {
                    owner: p1
                }
            })

            result.forEach(row => {
                console.log(`row number ${index}, url is: ${row.url}`)
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err)
        }
    }
})
```

And this is the output:

```
query is: SELECT url FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested` WHERE repository.owner = @owner
row number 0, url is: https://github.com/de3/Panada
row number 1, url is: https://github.com/schbern/samples
row number 2, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/47a1801f13...9dedbc8ce6
row number 3, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/38
row number 4, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/46934664ea...a7cae9f088
row number 5, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/175c88e2cb...47a1801f13
row number 6, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/1a35a44548...46934664ea
row number 7, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/256c9b4ed3...1f293ca245
row number 8, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/49c38b23e2...d948d2eb97
row number 9, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/38
row number 10, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/d948d2eb97...46b7bcde5f
row number 11, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/a7cae9f088...256c9b4ed3
row number 12, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/36
row number 13, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/pull/1
row number 14, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/pull/1
row number 15, url is: https://github.com/de3/documentation
row number 16, url is: https://github.com/cakyus/Panada
row number 17, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/9dedbc8ce6...4db3e50d80
row number 18, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/46b7bcde5f...52e9ef5c67
row number 19, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/issues/1#issuecomment-4533276
```

Answer (score 1):

If the query returns a result, your code throws the ReferenceError "url is not defined", because you are using "console.log(url)" instead of "console.log(row.url)".

The Error "Undeclared query parameters" is not related to that, though. It means that you are calling the function "test" without the necessary argument, like 'test()'. You have to pass a string to it, like 'test("UnionOfRAD")'.

A test code that worked for me:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

async function test(p1) {
  let [result] = await bigquery.query({
    query: [
      'SELECT url',
      'FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested`',
      'WHERE repository.owner = @owner'

    ].join(' '),
    params: {
      owner: p1
    }
  });
  result.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.url)
  })
}
test("UnionOfRAD")
```

Comment: Thank you but any reason why you answer with a similar answer to mine. It's customary to vote-up on an answer which is ok and not add duplicates. Tnk

Comment: Greetings, I think the answers are different as yours stated that the problem is in the use of "console.log(url)", but mine stated that the Error "Undeclared query parameters" is not related to that, it says the problem is in the calling of the function "test" without the necessary argument.

Comment: You are correct there were 2 different errors in the code described in the question. Typically good practice to add comments where possible and avoid multiple answers. Thank you. Feel free to vote-up :)

Comment: In the code described in the question I see these 2 errors: 
- Not closing the "forEach" with a bracket.
- The error that you pointed out, "console.log(url)".

The code lacks the call to the function "test", so I had to reproduce the issue with 'test()' and 'test("UnionOfRAD")' to arrive to the conclusion that the "Undeclared query parameters" error was caused by a call without the necessary argument, but I think the fact that the code doesn't explicitly show the call is not an error, as it is a snippet.

Comment: Yes, this is why in my answer I provided a full mocha test which you can copy/paste and execute.